# Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\blog\resources\views\admin\users\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

when I'm going to create a new user I get this type of error. And error mark over the image link. If I change image route like `$user->profile['avatar'])` it works, but in view page, it doesn't display the image.

view page:

```
<tbody>
    @if($users->count() > 0)
      @foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="{{asset($user->profile->avatar)}}" width="60px" height="60px" style="border-radius: 50%;">
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ $user->name }}
        </td>
        <td>

          @if($user->admin)

          <a href="{{route('user.not.admin',['id' => $user->id])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Remove permission</a>

          @else

          <a href="{{route('user.admin',['id' => $user->id])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Make admin</a>

          @endif

        </td>
        <td>
          delete
        </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
    @else
        <tr>
           <th colspan="5" class="text-center">No users available!</th>
        </tr>
    @endif

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt('password')
        ]);

        $profile = Profile::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'avatar' => 'uploads/avatars/1.png'
        ]);

        Session::flash('success', 'User created successfully!');

        return redirect()->route('users');
    }
```

Please help me to fix this problem. If you need more information about the code please let me know.

Comment: please show us the code of add user view blade template, maybe you misspelled the variable names in the view blade template.

Comment: also please show us your eloquent relation between profile and user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Is your query returning **array** or **object**? If you **dump** it out, you might find that it's an array and all you need is an array access ([]) instead of an object access (->).

Answer (score 0):

The `store` method seems to be good, the problem could be with the `index` method that returns your view with a list of users but not with the `profile` relation, you could try calling `$user->profile()->avatar` in your index view instead `$user->profile->avatar`. That way you're querying the relationship at the time of accessing it.

Comment: it says- Undefined property :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead

`$user->profile($id)['avatar'];`

considering that the input for your profile function is `$id` and the function returns the user profile information that you are fetching

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your object does not exist OR that it is an array...
Just add @ before your $user

```
 {{asset(@$user->profile->avatar)}}
```

Comment: What is your reasoning for suggesting to suppress an error instead of check for a non-object?

Answer (score 0):

from your post, I assume that you have a separate table for the profile, which is ideal.
what you need to do is open your `Profile` model and create a relationship like this;

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```